# Generated Alert on Availability Test is not fired

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, availability, azure-alerts

I've defined an availability test on a **Function App** (called watchdog) accessible with a function key. The watchdog performs an `URL-ping` on other health endpoints (protected by **AAD**). The JSON response is evaluated if one of the functions contains an `unhealthy` or `degraded` status the overall overall status will be `unhealthy` and the HTTP status will be **500**.

Watchdog results are correct, since I see proper outcomes when adding/removing **fails injection** into one of the watched functions.

The test is defined as follows:

```
Test type: URL ping test
URL: watchdog endpoint with function key
Parse dependent requests: unchecked
Enable retries for availability test failures: unchecked
Test frequency: 5 minutes
Test locations: West Europe
Test Timeout: 120 seconds
Status code must equal: 200
Content match: {successful JSON response}
Alerts: Enabled
```

I've selected the test and clicked on `Open Rules (Alerts) page` to edit the generated alert rule.
Then only thing I've added is an **action group** configured to send a message to my job mail.
I've double checked the mail for correctness. I've double checked my spam folder in outlook.

I've read docs, watched tutorials and investigated but I still have no clue about this alert is not properly fired.

If someone could put me on the right path, I'll be very grateful!

Regards,
Giacomo S. S.

Comment: What is the alert condition? That may be not getting triggered e.g. Failed Location >= 2 when only one is configured.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I checked. Failed Locations is set >= 1. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

This was happening cause in first place cause I've done a lot different configuration experiments, reaching maximum alerts.

Now the alert is properly fired and the email sent.